# Passing JS array value to a backing bean using <f:setPropertyActionListener />

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jsf, jstl

How can I pass an Array in JavaScript (basically some table rows selected by user) to a backing bean array using `f:setPropertyActionListener` or any other method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without being more specific I am going to assume that you are talking about a named array or a JSON object which first needs to be converted to a string.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function callBackingBean(myJSON) {
   var stringArray = JSON.stringify(myJSON);
   jQuery('#theClientIdOfTheField')[0].value = stringArray;
   var button = jQuery('#theClientIdofthebutton');
   button.click();
}
</script>

<h:inputHidden id="input1" value="#{managedBean.managedProperty}" />
<h:commandButton id="buttonid" style="display: none;" />
```

The strategy essentially is to use a hidden input that takes the JSON converted string as its value, while a hidden button is invoked from Javascript.  It need not even have a listener or action, but the resulting postback will cause the string to be updated to the managed property.

Comment: hello maple since i have more then one row to pass could you please help me how to do that ???

Comment: @user1501345 I assume that you are using a dataTable, and that you are asking about how to send a JSON object for every row into a managed property tells me that you probably don't understand the dataTable component very well.  Most third party dataTable controls have built in functionality that makes syncing their data to a managed property very easy, so without understanding your full use case I have to assume that you are going about this completely wrong.

Comment: Did you know that you only have to write `jQuery` in its long form once? By wrapping your code in `(function($) { .... })(jQuery);`, you can use `$` no matter if `noConflict` has been used or not. And you can simply use `.val(...)` instead of `[0].value = ...`

Comment: @ThiefMaster Yes I know this, but unfortunately the $ symbol is a reserved character in EL expressions which are heavily used in JSF applications.  This is why you will commonly see jQuery used in its long form in JSF applications.

Comment: @user1501345: Please stop posting inappropriate spammy comments like the ones you just posted. Pings are not meant to notify people about a new unrelated question you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Using f:setPropertyActionListener is not a proper solution for this problem. I recommend you to create h:inputHidden field, bind it to a bean property and update it's value using javascript (set the array info there). When the form is submitted your bean will receive the value you set before using javascript.

Comment: can u please help me out i dont know much how to update a hidden filed each time for a new row. It will be really help full if u post a code or sumthing .. thanx in advance

Comment: Will be better if you explain the exact use case. So we can be aware of what you are trying to do.